# Arguments against Inversion of Control containers

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container

Seems like everyone is moving towards IoC containers. I've tried to "grok" it for a while, and as much as I don't want to be the one driver to go the wrong way on the highway, it still doesn't pass the test of common sense to me. Let me explain, and please correct/enlighten me if my arguments are flawed:

My understanding: IoC containers are supposed to make your life easier when combining different components. This is done through either a) constructor injection, b) setter injection and c) interface injection. These are then "wired up" programmatically or in a file that's read by the container. Components then get summoned by name and then cast manually whenever needed.

What I don't get:

**EDIT**: *(Better phrasing)*
Why use an opaque container that's not idiomatic to the language, when you can "wire up" the application in (imho) a much clearer way if the components were properly designed (using IoC patterns, loose-coupling)? How does this "managed code" gain non-trivial functionality? (I've heard some mentions to life-cycle management, but I don't necessarily understand how this is any better/faster than do-it-yourself.)

**ORIGINAL**:
Why go to all the lengths of storing the components in a container, "wiring them up" in ways that aren't idiomatic to the language, using things equivalent to "goto labels" when you call up components by name, and then losing many of the safety benefits of a statically-typed language by manual casting, when you'd get the *equivalent* functionality by not doing it, and instead using all the cool features of abstraction given by modern OO languages, e.g. programming to an interface? I mean, the parts that actually need to use the component at hand have to know they are using it in any case, and here you'd be doing the "wiring" using the most natural, idiomatic way - programming!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are certainly [people who think that DI Containers add no benefit](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000783.html), and the question is valid. If you look at it purely from an object composition angle, the benefit of a container may seem negligible. Any third party can connect loosely coupled components.

However, once you move beyond toy scenarios you should realize that the third party that connects collaborators must take on more that the simple responsibility of composition. There may also be decommissioning concerns to prevent resource leaks. As the composer is the only party that knows whether a given instance was shared or private, it must also take on the role of doing **lifetime management**.

When you start combining various instance scopes, using a combination of shared and private services, and perhaps even scoping some services to a particular context (such as a web request), things become complex. It's certainly possible to write all that code with poor man's DI, but it doesn't add any business value - it's pure infrastructure.

Such infrastructure code constitutes a **Generic Subdomain**, so it's very natural to create a reusable library to address such concerns. That's exactly what a DI Container is.

BTW, most containers I know don't use names to wire themselves - they use **Auto-wiring**, which combines the static information from Constructor Injection with the container's configuration of mappings from interfaces to concrete classes. In short, containers natively understand those patterns.

A DI Container is not required for DI - it's just damned helpful.

---

A more detailed treatment can be found in the article [When to use a DI Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhenToUseADIContainer.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. Ok, I agree that generic functionality should be abstracted and made into a reusable component. And yes, some containers do make your life easier (most notable for me: application servers. From your reply, they seem similar enough to IoC containers). I haven't heard of auto-wiring (perhaps because it wasn't in the tutorials and beginner articles...) Perhaps I need to learn more about them, but until then I'll remain skeptical :)

Comment: @vivri: What's your platform? .NET? Java? Something else?

Comment: Currently I live in the Java ecosystem and we use Spring where I work, but (a) apparently we don't use it to its full potential (we use EJBs, which were apparently obsoleted by Spring), and (b) I haven't yet been exposed to anything that requires using it.

Comment: OK. I'm mostly familiar with .NET containers. There *are* differences across the platforms, but Spring.NET supports auto-wiring, although not to the same degree as the other .NET containers.

Comment: I'm guessing the differences have to do with .NET's support for lambdas.

Comment: No, lambdas have nothing to do with it. I would seriously expect Java containers to be able to do the same thing. Auto-wiring has been possible since .NET 1.0.

Comment: @vivri: it's absolutely not true that EJBs were "obsoleted by spring". Java EE (EJB) containers were the first widely available IoC-type thing in Java, but originally very inconvenient to use and did not implement DI. Spring appeared as an easier-to-use alternative with additional features (DI mainly). But the Java EE spec was updated too and got a complete overhaul with Version 3. At the moment, Java EE and Spring are pretty much tied for both features and ease of use, with Java EE having the added benefit of being an official standard with multiple implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Michael. We're working on an older version of JEE, so I don't see much of what you're talking about.

Comment: @Mark: The link to natpryce.com is broken.

Comment: @Mark: I got a "Server not found", but perhaps it's a local problem. Thanks for your response. I'm reading it now through the google cache.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure there's a lot to be said on the subject, and hopefully I'll edit this answer to add more later (and hopefully more people will add more answers and insights), but just a couple quick points to your post...

Using an IoC container is a subset of [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), not the whole thing.  You can use inversion of control as a design construct without relying on an IoC container framework.  At its simplest, inversion of control can be stated in this context as "supply, don't instantiate."  As long as your objects aren't internally depending on implementations of other objects, and are instead requiring that instantiated implementations be supplied to them, then you're using inversion of control.  Even if you're not using an IoC container framework.

To your point on programming to an interface... I'm not sure what your experience with IoC containers has been (my personal favorite is [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/)), but you definitely program to an interface with IoC.  The whole idea, at least in how I've used it, is that you separate your interfaces (your types) from your implementations (your injected classes).  The code which relies on the interfaces is programmed only to those, and the implementations of those interfaces are injected when needed.

For example, you can have an `IFooRepository` which returns from a data store instances of type `Foo`.  All of your code which needs those instances gets them from a supplied object of type `IFooRepository`.  Elsewhere, you create an implementation of `FooRepository` and configure your IoC to supply that anywhere an `IFooRepository` is needed.  This implementation can get them from a database, from an XML file, from an external service, etc.  Doesn't matter where.  That control has been inverted.  Your code which uses objects of type `Foo` doesn't care where they come from.

The obvious benefit is that you can swap out that implementation any time you want.  You can replace it with a test version, change versions based on environment, etc.  But keep in mind that you also don't need to have such a 1-to-1 ratio of interfaces to implementations at any given time.

For example, I once used a code generating tool at a previous job which spit out tons and tons of DAL code into a single class.  Breaking it apart would have been a pain, but what wasn't much of a pain was to configure it to spit it all out in specific method/property names.  So I wrote a bunch of interfaces for my repositories and generated this one class which implemented *all* of them.  For that generated class, it was ugly.  But the rest of my application didn't care because it saw each interface as its own type.  The IoC container just supplied that same class for each one.

We were able to get up and running quickly with this and nobody was waiting on the DAL development.  While we continued to work in the domain code which used the interfaces, a junior dev was tasked with creating better implementations.  Those implementations were later swapped in, all was well.

As I mentioned earlier, this can all be accomplished without an IoC container framework.  It's the pattern itself that's important, really.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David! I agree that using the IoC pattern is important and creates far superior APIs. My "beef" was with the usage of the frameworks and containers - I just don't see the point of storing object instances and "wiring up" your application in what amounts to an almost-virtual-machine that is opaque to you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all what is IOC? It means that responsibility of creating the dependent object is taken away from the main object and delegated to third party framework. I always use spring as my IOC framework and it bring tons of benefit to the table.

1. **Promotes coding to interface and decoupling** - The key benefit is that IOC promotes and makes decoupling very easy. You can always inject an interface in your main object and then use the interface methods to perform tasks. The main object does not need to know which dependent object is assigned to the interface. When you want to use a different class as dependency all you need is to swap the old class with a new one in the config file without a single line of code change. Now you can argue that this can be done in the code using various interface design patterns. But IOC framework makes its walk in a park. So even as a newbie you become expert in levering various interface design patterns like bridge, factory etc.
2. **Clean code** - As most of object creation and object life-cycle operations are delegated to IOC container you saved from the writing broiler point repetitive code. So you have a cleaner, smaller and more understandable code.
3. **Unit testing** - IOC makes unit testing easy. Since you are left with decoupled code you can easily test the decoupled code in isolation. Also you can easily inject dependencies in your test cases and see how different component interacts.
4. **Property Configurators** - Almost all the applications have some properties file where they store application specific static properties. Now to access those properties developers need to write wrappers which will read and parse the properties file and store the properties in format that application can access. Now all the IOC frameworks provide a way of injecting static properties/values in specific class. So this again becomes walk in the park.

These are some of the points I can think right away I am sure there are more.